# div position + operator does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, css

How come this works:

```
newDiv.style.top = topBar.style.height.split("px")[0]+"px";
->>><div style="top: 30.31px;" class="lineSeparator"></div>
```

And this works too

```
newDiv.style.top = topBar.style.height.split("px")[0]-2+"px";
->>><div style="top: 28.31px;" class="lineSeparator"></div>
```

And this works too

```
newDiv.style.top = topBar.style.height.split("px")[0]/2+"px";
->>><div style="top: 15.15px;" class="lineSeparator"></div>
```

**But this does not work:**

```
newDiv.style.top = topBar.style.height.split("px")[0]+2+"px";
->>><div style="top: 30.31px;" class="lineSeparator"></div>
```

I also tried:

```
newDiv.style.top = (topBar.style.height.split("px")[0]+2)+"px";
```

This is my full code:

```
function generateSeparators(n){
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
        var newDiv=document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.style.top = topBar.style.height.split("px")[0]+"px";
        newDiv.className = "lineSeparator";
        sideBar.appendChild(newDiv);

    }
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean, and where's the HTML this applies to?

Comment: It's much easier for others to help you if you describe what happens with the "does not work" version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `+` operator in Javascript, unlike `/` and `-`, also performs string concatenation. You must first coerce your first string operand to a number. Otherwise the "string" part will overpower the "number" part. For instance:

```
"3" + 2 --> "32"
```

This would be one way to fix your code:

```
newDiv.style.top = ((+topBar.style.height.split("px")[0])+2)+"px";
```

This would probably be a better, clearer way:

```
newDiv.style.top = (parseInt(topBar.style.height.split("px")[0], 10) + 2) + "px";
```

(The 10 parameter to parseInt means to interpret the string as a base-10 number. See the documentation for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt )

Comment: Thank you very much! I really did not know how to describe the question better than this but you found the problem in a matter of seconds. Thank you very much. I will accept the answer in 7 minutes. Much love!